# How do I configure an AWS network load balancer with an A record in Cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balance

I am trying to use an AWS Network Load Balancer to point at a group of servers. I would then like to take my DNS and point it at the load balancer. However, after I set everything up I cannot find and ip address for the AWS load balancer. I only see a URL value but the A-record in Cloudflare requires an actual IP.

How do I configure the DNS to point at the Load Balancer?

Answer (score 2):

You create a `CNAME` record referencing the assigned hostname of the balancer as the target.

`CNAME` records are not valid at the apex of a zone (i.e. the "naked" domain, without `www` or any other prefix) but Cloudflare allows you to create one there -- sort of -- they actually allow you to *believe* that you're creating one there, and then their service automatically transforms it into one or more valid A-records, dynamically.

This feature is enabled by default at the apex.

https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/

Comment: I will try it out but I def need the apex as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying in this comment.  As I indicated, above, this does work at the apex in Cloudflare.